# Unable to test WCF Endpoints with IntelliTest

Tags: c#, wcf, intellitest

I'm trying to test my WCF Service Endpoints using `IntelliTest` I've created the `IntelliTest` units in a test project, but I need to specify the Server address and port in order for the test to remotely even to work.

This is one of the `PexMethods`

```
public ICredentials CredentialsTest()
{
    ICredentials result = Service.Credentials();
    return result;
    // TODO: add assertions to method ServiceTest.CredentialsTest()
}
```

I've added

```
Service.ServiceEndPointAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:51010/WCFService";
```

but when I run the test I get an `InvalidProgramException`.

What I would like to do is assign the ServiceEndPointAddress once as it is a static property in Service. Anybody that can give some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Getting an InvalidProgramException indicates that IntelliTest has instrumented your code in such a manner as to cause the underlying CLR to raise the exception. That would be a bug in IntelliTest. I request you to file this using the Send a Smile in Visual Studio.
2. You should not use IntelliTest to directly explore your WCF code. Instead, you should isolate the WCF related external dependencies using mocks (much as you would do if you were writing unit tests by hand), and then run IntelliTest to explore the resultant code. For mocking you can consider using Fakes.